# How to create Departments and assign users to each in Seratec Central 8.2.1

Tags: myob

I'm trying to create new Departments and assign my company users to each department without touching the Database and only using the Central window. However I cannot edit existing department or add any new department to it. It would be great, if someone can help me with this.

Version: Seratec Central 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Seratec Central was written by Seratec Pty Ltd and interacts with MYOB software such as AccountRight via APIs and is a [3rd party integration](http://myob.com.au/addons/listing/17/seratec-central/); it is not AFAIK owned or maintained by MYOB[*].

Their website is [down](http://www.seratec.com.au/contact-us/) and I suspect the [operation has folded](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Seratec+Pty+Ltd).

I would suggest you try and find other Seratec users perhaps via [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/company/seratec-pty-ltd) or the [MYOB community forums](http://myob.com.au/business/customer-service-support/support/myob-community-forum-1257828421443).

[*] I could be wrong